# How can increase Google speech API queries Request more than 50

Tags: google-speech-api

Currently I am using the Google Speech API, where I followed [J.A.R.V.I.S. (Java-Speech-API)](https://github.com/lkuza2/java-speech-api). It's working very fine for me, but I can do only 50 queries per day, is there any way to increase the number of queries per day.

Please give some suggestion for this.

Answer (score 0):

That speech API is for personal and testing use only [and you won't get an increased quota](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-dev/TJRsxtxkB_Y/jaCX307c1tQJ). Many have asked, but the position is still the same today.

You need to use the [new Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/)